Which one helps here login redirect or login popup? How to handle efficiently when error occurred during token retrieval from msal-react.js
Below is my code where i retrieve token. But how to handle when error occurred this token retrieval method? i will be calling in both during the initial load flow and also during any button click events as well. Please suggest a good method to handle errors.
    import { AccountInfo, InteractionRequiredAuthError, PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";import fetchConfigs from "../../configs/authConfig";
 
class AuthService {
   private msalInstance!: PublicClientApplication;
   private initialized: boolean = false;
   private tokenScope: any;

   constructor() {
      this.initializeMsalInstance();
   }
   private async initializeMsalInstance(): Promise<void> {
       if (!this.initialized) {
           const { msalConfig, tokenScope } = await fetchConfigs;
           this.tokenScope = tokenScope;
           this.msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
           await this.msalInstance.initialize();
           this.initialized = true;
       }   }
   async generateToken(): Promise<{ tokenResponse: { token: string | null, expiresOn: Date | null } }> {
       try {
           await this.initializeMsalInstance();
           const accounts = this.msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
           if (accounts.length > 0) {
               const tokenResponse = await this.msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
                   ...this.tokenScope,
                   account: accounts[0]
               });               if (tokenResponse) {
                  return {
                       tokenResponse: {
                           token: tokenResponse?.accessToken,
                           expiresOn: tokenResponse.expiresOn ? new Date(tokenResponse?.expiresOn) : null                       }                   };               }           }       }       catch (error) {
           if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
               try {
                   // Interaction required, initiate login using a popupconst loginResponse = await this.msalInstance.loginPopup(this.tokenScope);
                   console.log('login response: ' + loginResponse);
                   // After successful login, try to acquire the token againconst tokenResponse = await this.msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
                      ...this.tokenScope,
                       account: loginResponse.account                   });                   console.log('popup token ' + tokenResponse);
                   return {
                       tokenResponse: {
                           token: tokenResponse.accessToken || null,
                           expiresOn: tokenResponse.expiresOn ? new Date(tokenResponse.expiresOn) : null
                       }
                   };
               } catch (popupError) {
                   console.error('popup login failed', popupError);
               }
           } else {
               console.error('silent token acquisition failed', error);
           }
       }
       return { tokenResponse: { token: null, expiresOn: null } };
   }
   }
export default AuthService;

